# Slight difference in MYSQL search condition makes huge difference, can't wrap my mind around it

Tags: mysql, geolocation

I can't say I'm an expert in MySQL, more on the novice side. But I'm aware of some basic performance cost concept. Having said that,

I have a table of user profiles of about 1 million rows. I want to filter the values and get back only what I'm interested in.

Among the columns, I have latitude and longitude columns.

In order to filter the "distance" aspect of it, I create an arbitrary rectangle with **latitude range** and **longitude range**.

Along with the "distance" attribute, I also have a few generic attributes I also filter with: like age, gender, etc.

I indexed all the fields including latitude and longitude. I use FLOAT type for lat and long, BTW.

So, it's a simple SELECT query, with multiple attributes, like so,

```
SELECT user_id FROM profiles WHERE gender = 1 AND birthday BETWEEN '1980-01-27' AND '1988-01-27' AND longitude BETWEEN -105 AND -103.6 AND latitude BETWEEN 35 AND 40
```

************ Here's the weirdest thing **************

When I test with filter values of longitude between, say -105 and -103.6, (along with other attributes), the query runs relatively quick (49ms). But when I change the longitude values to be between -105 and -103.5 (0.1 difference!), the query takes 493ms. (10 times!?!?!?!)

The resulting select result difference is only a few hundred (understandably so).

---

So I try changing other values as well, to see what the heck is causing this. I change latitude values around. Latitude value doesn't seem to have any effect on the performance. WTF!

I go as far as to remove the indexing, and try different variations of indexing just to get at the problem.

Still not a clue.

So, I go deeper into this, I change the longitude value to be between -105 and -103.597. -103.597 takes 49ms, while -105 and -103.596 takes 526ms.

0.001 difference can't possibly make that kind of difference in query performance. **WHAT AM I MISSING???**

I'm using InnoDB, mysql version 5.7.19, btw.

table schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `user_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orientation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `birthday` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
  `height` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ethnicity` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `latitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`),
  KEY `birthday` (`birthday`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Depend from many factor  .. so you should update your question .. add your query,, your table schema and  a reasonable data sample

Comment: I added some additional info, let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: You can check what MySQL is doing by looking at the query plan, run `EXPLAIN <query>` for both cases.

Comment: It seems that I might've gotten a lead in finding my problem, the number of rows when it's -103.5 is about 500,000 while when it's -103.6, it's about 77000. That's what seems to be causing the problem. And there's difference in Extra field as well... Thanks. let me dig deeper into this.

Comment: OK. Apparently the slight difference in query value is changing the execution plan. And the plan is determined by MySQL, but apparently, their optimizer isn't doing a very good job. I now need a way to alter the execution plan somehow. Thanks so much for the info!

Comment: Afaik the order of indexes doesn't matter. What probably happened is that the index statistics got updated. You should drop the index on `gender`, the only thing it does is generating dumb execution plans. An index with only a few possible values and uniform distribution only creates problems.

Comment: You're right. I had to fiddle with the indexing a little, I fixed it by adding multiple-column index like so, 
KEY `birthday` (`birthday`,`longitude`,`latitude`,`gender`) so solve my problem. Thanks! Vatev!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL runs an internal optimizer to determine an execution plan for all queries.

The slight change in the query (in my case) caused the optimizer to come up with a totally different execution plan, hence the huge different in the result for a slight change in one of the values.

The way I fixed it is by changing the structure of the table, (indexes, etc.) so that MySQL will have a better idea when coming up with execution plan. In my case, fixing the indexes did the trick. I added multi column index to somewhat force the optimizer to go a certain route.

This is as far as I got to it, Thanks to all the commenters for the help.